# AngularJs can't set selected option by ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I need to preselect my select rendered by ng-repeat

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div>Operator is: {{openAccount.leverage}}</div>
    <select class="form-control" name="leverage" ng-model="openAccount.leverage">
        <option ng-repeat="leverage in currentType.leverageList"
                value="{{leverage}}" ng-selected="{{currentType.defaultLeverage == openAccount.leverage}}">1:{{leverage}}
        </option>
    </select>
</body>

function AppCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.currentType = {};
    $scope.currentType.leverageList = ['10','20','30'];
    $scope.currentType.defaultLeverage = '20';
}
```

This is my code and here is fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/FxM3B/440/

Comment: ng-selected="{{currentType.defaultLeverage == openAccount.leverage}}"..  What you are trying to do with this logic..What's openAccount.leverage value?

Comment: I'm triyng to make option SELECTED. I found this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/coverbeck/FxM3B/5/

Comment: In your example fiddle they have given a default value to openAccount.leverage, your code is incomplete..

Comment: Check my answer and this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FxM3B/441/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code worked for me.

```
<option 
    ng-repeat="leverage in currentType.leverageList"
    value="{{leverage}}"
    ng-selected="{{currentType.defaultLeverage == leverage}}">1:{{leverage}}</option>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypwvg8L7/)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This saved my neck.

Comment: any time Mauro :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try repeating the `select` options with the [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) directive.

```
<select ng-options="item.subItem as item.label for item in values track by item.id" ng-model="selected">
```

Example out of the AngularJS docs.

Comment: Please could you change my fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div>Operator is: {{openAccount.leverage}}</div>
  <select class="form-control" name="leverage" ng-model="openAccount.leverage">
  <option 
   ng-repeat="leverage in currentType.leverageList"
   value="{{leverage.value}}"
  ng-selected="{{openAccount.leverage == leverage.value}}"{{leverage.value}}</option>
</select>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function AppCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.openAccount ={
        leverage : '20'
    }
    $scope.currentType = {};
    $scope.currentType.leverageList = [
         {value: '10', displayName: '10'},
         {value: '20', displayName: '20'},        
         {value: '30', displayName: '30'} 
    ]      
 }
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FxM3B/441/)